# make "print to file" settings permanent in Iceape [Seamonkey]

Tags: printing, pdf, browser

Everytime I want to "print to file", say, a website in Iceape [Seamonkey] in Linux [Debian], I have to set all the options for printing anew to overwrite the default settings. Not just every time I restart the browser but for every single document!

**Question**: How to set "Title" in the top left corner and "Page x of y" in the bottom right corner once and for all. All other fields should be empty: no URL, no date, no nothing – this should be also set once and for ever.

Answer (score 1):

To get `.pdf` files from `print to file` with the defined header and footer in Iceape [Seamonkey], I found the following way:

### Get Default Values

1. Open the address `about:config` via  Iceape's [Seamonkey's] Location Bar. One is asked to continue only if one is sure what one does… [as always: make notes what you've changed and resetting will be much simpler in, say, a year from now]
2. Enter `printer_PostScript/default.print_` in the field next to **Filter:**
3. look for the following entries:
   [image: entries to be edited for making printer settings permanently]

### Customize Values

4. right-click on one of the entries and choose "Modify"
5. edit the entries, according to the following syntax:

Valid Values are:

- **&T**   Title of the document
- **&U**   URL
- **&D**   Date/time
- **&P**   Page number
- **&PT** Page x of y
- for *empty* delete the contents
- (any string): A literal string with the above substitutions made

**→ Source**: [Mozilla Knowledge Base About:config entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)

The settings in the image above will result in exactly what is asked: *Title* in the Upper Left Corner and the *Page Count* [page x of y] in the bottom right corner. All other fields are empty